# Change time on windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, time

I would like to change the date/time on a windows 2003 box that is a part of an AD domain to a day far in the past for a period of time.  Is this possible without the box resyncing with the DC, and still maintaining its membership in the domain (authentication and such)?

I need the date on the server to be a specific date for some data processing. The software uses the local system time, and I need it to import data based on a date in the past. I can detach the server from the domain and do it, but I'm looking for a way to do it keeping it on the domain

I was hoping to avoid taking it out of AD because I need to do it around 30 times today, changing the date each time.

Comment: Sounds like somebody had a demo license expire.

Comment: How is that helpful?

Comment: It wasn't, thanks Joseph.  I need the date on the server to be a specific date for some data processing.  The software uses the local system time, and I need it to import data based on a date in the past.  I can detach the server from the domain and do it, but I'm looking for a way to do it keeping it on the domain.

Comment: That's why it's a comment. :-) Helpful items should be posted below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it by disabling the time service but it will break security because kerberos requires the time to be sync'd (default 5mins max difference)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780011(WS.10).aspx

Comment: And breaking kerberos, will break your ability to login anywhere else on the network (from that system).

Comment: Thanks.  Even though it wasn't the answer I was hoping for, this showed me what I am trying to do is probably impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You ought to be able to disable the Windows Time service so that the resynchronisation doesn't happen, however I would imagine the system won't be liekd by the AD. You should still be able to use the system, but whether or not it will be accepted by the domain I can't say (probably not).

Answer (score 1):

I would:

1. Take it out of AD
2. Reset the BIOS clock
3. Process your data
4. Reset the BIOS clock
5. Add the system back into AD

There are probably other ways to do this. But since you only need to do this once, do it in a manner that causes the least amount of AD errors.

Comment: Thats how I do it now.  Was hoping to avoid taking it out of AD because I need to do it around 30 times today changing the date each time.

Comment: Wow really? 30 times? That should be in your initial post.

Comment: I just updated your post a bit. Hope there's a better answer than "turning off the time service", probably not though.

Answer (score 1):

If U must change time U can try this:

set up Network syncronize time server (NTP) in AD Admin as other linux machine in Connection settings then change datetime on linux machine by:

date --set="03 DEC 2011 12:13:12"

Linux must be a NTP server.

it will change time on all AD computers

For me works perfect on all AD servers :)

REGARDS.